# Plugin.php: PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in

Tags: plugins, php, errors

I moved a WordPress site from one domain to another and there were a lot of white spaces that needed to be removed.

The only problem that is left are the following errors:

- PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/linguist/public_html/test/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 767
- PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/linguist/public_html/test/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 785

then further

PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/linguist/public_html/test/wp-includes/plugin.php:767)

Its all due to this code which hasn't been changed at all but is creating errors.

```
if (is_object($function[0]) ) {
    // Object Class Calling
    if ( function_exists('spl_object_hash') ) {
        return spl_object_hash($function[0]) . $function[1];
    } else {
        $obj_idx = get_class($function[0]).$function[1];
        if ( !isset($function[0]->wp_filter_id) ) {
            if ( false === $priority )
                return false;
            $obj_idx .= isset($wp_filter[$tag][$priority]) ? count((array)$wp_filter[$tag][$priority]) : $filter_id_count;
            $function[0]->wp_filter_id = $filter_id_count;
            ++$filter_id_count;
        } else {
            $obj_idx .= $function[0]->wp_filter_id;
        }

        return $obj_idx;
    }
} else if ( is_string($function[0]) ) {
    // Static Calling
    return $function[0].$function[1];
}
```

}

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: You remove whitespaces? Where do you remove them? This code is throwing an error because it is called with a wrong parameter. So the real error is at another palce.

Answer (score 4):

Some code on your site registers a filter or an action with invalid arguments. The errors you see happen, because `add_action()` or `add_filter()` was called with a second argument that is not a string, an object or an array.

Examples:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', NULL );
add_filter( 'the_content', -1 );
```

Disable all plugins, switch to Twenty Eleven, and re-enable everything until the errors comes back. Then find all calls to `add_action()` or `add_filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which command is the reason. Add the following code before the line "if ( is_object( $function[0] ) ) {"

```
if(!isset($function[0])){
    var_dump($tag);
    var_dump($function);
    var_dump($priority);
    die();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/linguist/public_html/test/wp-includes/plugin.php:767)

you just put ob_start() in your functions.php at the top of the line.

Comment: Hiding errors is wrong. They should be fixed instead.

Comment: The `headers already sent` error is caused by the output of the first error(s). So you can ignore this. If you fix the previous error(s), this error will also be gone.